# Is this expected behaviour of entity framework or bug?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

i was working with Entity framework version 6.1.3 and found an unexpected behaviour, so i have created a small code that can reproduce it

when i execute below code, and see in database vehicle's userid is set to previously inserted user. it should throw exception related to referential integrity

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            dbContext.Users.Add(new User { Email = "x@b.com", Name = "x" });
            dbContext.Vehicles.Add(new Vehicle { BuildYear = 2016, Model = "BMW X4" });
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int BuildYear { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

i am using code first approach. when i see result in database, userid in vehicle table is last inserted user id.
there is no triggers in database AFAIK

this is what i am seeing in SSMS

[image]

Comment: @GertArnold i am 100% sure that there is no triggers in that database

Comment: @GertArnold I've been able to reproduce this with fresh code first project, it even occurs with detectchanges/proxy creation disabled

Comment: It's very weird, it also only happens when I add `School` and `Teacher` in one roundtrip to database. If I add only a `Teacher` (while there are already `School` in database) I get an error because the required foreign key isn't filled in (as expected)

Comment: @GertArnold you can simply copy paste and recreate this issue

Answer (score 2):

Here's what happens:

```
dbContext.Users.Add(new User { Email = "x@b.com", Name = "x" });
```

A `User` object has been created having `Id = 0`.

```
dbContext.Vehicles.Add(new Vehicle { BuildYear = 2016, Model = "BMW X4" });
```

A `Vehicle` has been created, having `UserId = 0`.

**Because of the identical key values, EF considers both objects as connected.**

When `SaveChanges` runs, EF executes *relationship fixup* by which it populates `Vehicle.User` and sets `Vehicle.UserId` to the new user's Id value, which it obtained from the database.

You correctly expected a referential constraint to be violated, as `UserId` can't be `null` and you don't seem to set it. The only way you can fix this is by setting the `Vehicle`'s `User` property. You can't set `Vehicle.UserId` because the `User`'s Id isn't known yet:

```
var user = new User { Email = "x@b.com", Name = "x" };
dbContext.Users.Add(user);
dbContext.Vehicles.Add(new Vehicle { BuildYear = 2016, Model = "BMW X4", User = user });
```

(By the way, I was side-tracked by the phrase *previously inserted user*, which suggested EF connected a user you inserted before running your code).

Comment: it would be better to have referential integrity error. By the way while checking for related entities at save time, it may ignore foreign keys with default values using default(type)

Comment: As for EF, there is no referential integrity error. The value 0 is a valid key value. Yes, if the key is nullable, the objects won't get connected, but you want `UserId` to be required. You should validate for it being > 0, e.g. by implementing `IValidatableObject`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not filling in the `UserId` property, so that property will be `0` by default value. Your `User` (I assume it's the first user you insert as it's testcode) will get `Id = 0` from the database too. So when you save them both, `Vehicle` will have a foreign key relationship with your first `User`.

What you're doing is not correct by the way. If your `Vehicle` navigation property can be null, you should make the corresponding foreign key `Nullable` too. Otherwise you have to assign a `User` to every new `Vehicle` you create.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find it documented anywhere, but apparently because there's a required relationship between vehicle and user, and you add both in one batch, Entity Framework decides that they must belong together, instead of executing the specified queries and letting the database return a referential constraint error.

I can't say I like this.

The solution, as you commented that you want this relation to be optional, is to make the `UserId` of type `int?`. Then the described behavior will not occur.

Comment: your proposed solution will work, but i am not assigning user to navigational property, so better it should throw referential integrity exception.

Answer (score 1):

It's an EF behaviour.

Vehicle.Id and User.Id are generated as autonumbering fields.
Vehicle.UserId is the field that is associated by default to the id of the Vehicle.User relationship.

With your classes, if you don't set Vehicle.User you also must have added **one and only one** User in the context that will be associated with the vehicle otherwise you will receive an exception.

If you change the UserId to optional the behaviour changes as expected and the user is not automatically associated but it will be Always the same as Vehicle.User.Id